# Can't embed external content on website

Tags: intershop

I want to embed external content on a website in an iframe. I can only load internal websites and external are undefined.
How can I enable CORS in Intershop 7.7 and load an external URL in an iframe or data dialog?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing special in using iframes in Intershop compared to another platform. Simply put in your ISML:

```
<iframe src="https://example.com">
</iframe>
```

Of course this may not succeed to load as you noticed. Some servers include the `X-Frame-Options` header with value e.g. `SAMEORIGIN` which instructs the browser that they don't want to be framed on other sites. This may be used to prevent *[clickjacking](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Clickjacking)* attacks. You may use Firebug or any appropriate tool to monitor for such errors during the frame load. An iframe may also not load if you mix http/s traffic.

If you want to *programatically* access content from an iframe on a different domain, you may use the [Web Messaging API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) (`window.postMessage` and the `onmessage` event) to communicate between the page and the included iframe.

In summary:

- you can't simply frame any site (maybe your 'internal' site permits that);
- this question is not relevant for the Intershop technology stack;

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible with the content security policy support since version 7.6.

Please check the documentation of appserver.properties file. The keys intershop.response.content-security-policy. should help.